# Connecting to WPA & WPA2 enterprise Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I'm having a hard time trying to connect to a WPA protected wi-FI with My Lenovo 710s running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. The wi-fi does not need any CA certificate only username and paasword. The problem im having is that sometimes it connects, sometimes it just randomly dc's and Im not able to reconnect and sometimes I cant connect at all. I can connect to any other wi-fi except this one.

I've tried Downgrading My wpa_supplicant to version 2.1 with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to restart your wireless adapter? sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service

Comment: I've had similar issues with Acer Chromebooks and the IT person told me that it wad a problem of WiFi standards. He added a standard to the access points and all worked ok.

Comment: It seems strange though that the problem would lie in the wi-fi since I can connect at some occasions.